# What happens when a user is deleted

Tags: support, deleted-users

If a user is deleted then all upvotes and downvotes cast by that user have been removed.

If a deleted user has posted a good question or an accepted answer, what will happen then?

When is a question deleted or maintained with a dummy name?

If a post is deleted at this time, is that justified?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a user account is deleted, *in the majority of cases* all their votes are undone too. There is an exception for high-rep user accounts that have been around for a long time; reverting their extensive voting would have too big an impact.

The system deletes posts *with a negative score* (so below 0) when an account is deleted. The rest is kept. If a question with a negative score is deleted, so will any answers to that post, regardless of their score.

See:

- [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470/what-does-user-was-removed-mean-and-why-did-my-reputation-change-because-of-it/126471#126471)
- [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)