# Why was this question deleted so quickly?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-user

About an hour ago I answered the question: [Wrong output for sum of digits using loop c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834772/wrong-output-for-sum-of-digits-using-loop-c). Easy beginner question, easy answer.

[image]

I came back to the browser tab just now and reloaded, but instead of seeing useful feedback like upvotes or even an accepted answer, I found the question had been deleted by the Community user, about 10 minutes after my answer! Nobody had voted to delete, or even voted to close. What the heck happened here? It only had one (undeserved, IMO) downvote when it was deleted.

I notice also that the user account no longer exists. Again, what happened here?

Comment: @iCodez: Uh, so okay, why was the user deleted? The duplicate does not answer my question: *What happened here?* Under normal circumstances, user accounts do not vanish an hour after being created.

Comment: The user self-deleted their own account, which took all negatively scored posts with it.

Comment: I see. I guess I should have hit the upvote button earlier when I still had the chance.

Comment: Does it matter why the user was deleted?  It is either because they deleted their own account (which is what happened here) or because they were kicked off the site for repeated bad behavior.  Either way, this would have happened.  Personally though, I find it annoying.  All of the care and effort you put into your answers is destroyed because a question *happened* to get a downvote.  Just because one user was removed doesn't mean your answer couldn't help others.

Comment: @iCodez: I was unaware that anonymous users could self-delete their own account. Learn something new every day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The user deleted their own account, which [triggered automatic deletion of their downvoted posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260443/what-happens-when-a-user-is-deleted). Or post, as the case may be.

I've undeleted the question.

For future reference, the rules for self-deletion are documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: Great, now I can add the upvote the question so richly deserves. :)

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/what-roomba-script-went-after-this-question#comment18430_6821