# How frequently do new users self-delete their own accounts?

Tags: discussion, statistics, deleted-users

According to [Help Center > My Account](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account), it is possible for new users to delete their own account as long as they have not voted or posted more than once.

Occasionally, this [causes otherwise legitimate questions to be deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276443/why-was-this-question-deleted-so-quickly), just because such questions happened to have a negative vote score at the moment the user opted to self-delete their account.

How frequently does this sort of thing happen? That is, how often does a new user self-deletion take their sole posted question with them?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the past 365 days, 18,984 users have deleted themselves.

Along with these user deletions, 1,484 questions have been deleted.  Of these, 612 had at least 1 answer, 265 of which were upvoted or accepted.

Since someone will probably ask, 99 answers were also deleted due to their authors self-deleting.

Comment: How new were these users? How long were they active on average before deleting their account?

Comment: I think new users should be allowed to delete their account only if there is no upvoted or accepted answer.

Comment: @Rahul: I don't think that restricting account self-deletion per se is a good solution. It might be better to allow the users to self-delete their account like now, but add a check to the question auto-deletion code it triggers to prevent question deletion if any of the answers has a lot (say, 3 or more) upvotes.

Comment: @Rahul: In any case, I'm not even convinced that there's much net gain to be had by tweaking the current system. Sure, occasionally, a marginally useful answer to a poor question may get deleted when the OP deletes their account; but, IME, *most* questions that get deleted that way are trivial [typo questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252585/recent-changes-to-close-reasons-on-stack-overflow) whose answers, even though they may be correct and gain occasional upvotes, will never help anyone *but* the OP, since they're essentially unsearchable.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, Yes may be and I am not concerned about user deleting their account. rather, if the provided answer is good then that answer must be preserved. Believe me, it has already happened with me; where question was related to DB concept.

Comment: At the very least, we should let all users see their answers to deleted questions, so they can at least find a better home for their answer.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: It is already implemented (recently deleted answer/question feature), but without any notification, most people usually don't notice.

Comment: @nhahtdh: A non-deleted answer to a deleted question doesn't count as a deleted answer for that feature.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: It **does** count, since I currently have one answer (not deleted by me) belongs to a deleted question, and it shows up in the list.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: The posting date of the answer counts. If a question was deleted and your answer is less than 60 days old, it'll be listed in that view. So [this post is listed for me](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26681463), [this answer is not](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24485607) even though both questions were deleted in the past few days.