# User was removed. -10, OK, but on which answer?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, deleted-users

You all know this:

> -10   N hours ago *removed*   User was removed ([learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/user-was-removed))

Just out of curiosity,
since logically one of our answers lost rep points can we see what's the related answer that suffered a -10 rep points change (1 vote)?

- Was that +10 given from the actual (removed) person who was the actual OP? (In that case I think it does not matters since the [Q&A are all deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260443/what-happens-when-a-user-is-deleted)...)
- If the removed person was not the OP, that means that the answer that got a stat change is still alive? If so, which one? Wouldn't it be a nice **feature to get a link to the page in question**?

Comment: Why does it matter at all?  If the user was removed, what real good does it do one to know which answer was impacted by their presence?

Comment: @Makoto you know, me as many people are driven by curiosity even if it burns ;) - Imagine it could be an interesting Answer that now shares votes with other 5 answers, might be good time to review your answer to make it better and *Stand out*. I mean, I perform regular checks on my old answers, but here's an extra reason to take action. And a curious one.

Comment: I always have had the same question in my mind when I lose votes for a removed user, but then I tell myself, "after all voting is anonymous".

Comment: In such a case I mourn the loss of an upvoted answer way more than the deleted user. After all, I did spend some time crafting it - and surely it could have been useful for others?

Comment: I'm active for 5+y on SO, some answers are worth revising > specially if you notice *that (which one?)* answer lost 1 upvote. (I frankly don't give a dime about rep. (in some odd way...)) and as far as I'm concerned about flaws in the mod tools and privileges... there's no way to jeopardize a deleted user any way. **Just show me my Answer**.

Comment: I recently got -10 (User removed), but I can still see on which post it was in the reputation history on iOS app. Is it a bug maybe (although arguably somewhat useful bug)?

Comment: @Roko "...many people are driven by curiosity even if it burns ;)" https://xkcd.com/242/ :)

Comment: Hmm, what if it was actually for *two* votes?  On questions.  What if that user upvoted a hundred other posts?  It doesn't scale, that's why they don't want to do this.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not concerned about Questions (and deleted users who voted on questions). I'm concerned about not receiving a link to the Answer (my answer) who's degraded since the lost vote. Even if the deleted user was an alter-upvote-ego (ghost/second profile) > no problem, If the removed user upvoted 10, 20 or more of my answers > the only issue here is that in that case I'd receive 20+ links to downgraded answers (inside a single notification). Even than, if that user was deleted, who would ever know. Now... seems that we're touching here a Pandora's box better left closed.

Comment: related: [Grace Period to recover deleted answer content (User Removed)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276508/grace-period-to-recover-deleted-answer-content-user-removed)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I sympathize with the curiosity that would lead to this request, but I suspect if this were made visible then it would be too easy in some cases to determine how a specific person voted.

Even though their account is gone, votes are *still* anonymous; potentially leaking this information could lead to problems.

Comment: That's a pity. I thought about that case, but than, if that specific person is removed, how would one possibly know which user was in question? Taking into account that his profile is not any more publicly visible and there's no records of *Recently removed users* (I guess)

Comment: For many users, it'd be pretty difficult, but if you could identify *one* action associated with the deleted user then it'd become trivial to identify a whole lot of other actions simply by associating the timestamps. Imagine, for instance, you came across a negatively-scored post that was removed at the time of deletion, or simply knew who upvoted *one* a specific post through other means. This... isn't actually a hypothetical concern, but I hope you'll forgive me for not revealing the specific person whose deletion we screwed up once upon a time and whose votes were laid bare for all to see.

Comment: Wasn't that when you still removed all votes, however active the user was?

Comment: No, although there was a different bug associated with us *not* doing that. If we'd removed all the votes, there wouldn't have been a problem for the same reason this feature-request exists @Deduplicator.

Comment: Nit picking: votes are not anonymous, they are protected.

Comment: I'm confused (to the point nearly opening a question myself about that):  When a (not-high-rep) user upvotes an answer and then gets deleted, the answerer (and others as well) can see their loss of rep and thus deduce that this deleted user upvoted that question, thus the voting is laid open.  Is that intended?  Furthermore:  Was it considered that this fact might lead to users refrain from deleting their account to avoid exactly this situation?

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd "*Nit picking: votes are not anonymous, they are protected*" To put it correctly, "voting is anonymous".

Comment: @Alfe: Account deletion has no timestamp visible on the user page, and is usually not noticed for some time. So working out which one it was, out of who knows how many users got deleted in the last hour/day/week, is non-trivial. If you already have a guess as to who voted, deletion can help confirm that, but that's about it.

Comment: Assuming  you have more than one answer, the election rep-event doesn't tell you which answer was downvoted, @Alfe. That information is what this feature-request is... requesting.

Comment: *`"Even though their account is gone, votes are still anonymous"`* - **Well great!!** If a **profile is gone** and you show me my downgraded Answer > logically *that user* will still be anonymous. Don't you think? There's no other logical way around it. Not AFAICS.

Comment: I never said we "cannot", @Roko. I said we *shouldn't*. You should think about this a little bit more: it is not uncommon to extract information from metadata that isn't explicit. In this case, the metadata is time and post; the time of deletion would serve to associate votes with a single user, and the posts would allow you to potentially identify commonalities between the votes (for instance, the presence of other answerers on the same question, or even the author of questions themselves). Also, I must reiterate: this isn't a hypothetical concern; this happened once; we won't do it again.

Comment: @Shog9 (P.S: I removed that *"cannot"* before you-commenting.)
Since the impact on a huge amount of DB tables (and it's repercussions) you don't touch users with high rep, that means that a low-rep user *only* can get *Deleted*, i must believe that among such a high volume of base transactions that happen every minute, such log could absolutely vanish unnoticed. Even more, I'm not talking about retaliation on D-votes and revenge actions, it's about a *Specific Answer* getting downgraded cause of a user that might got banned for other reasons (that are not an up-v. on *Nice & Valid* Answers)...

Comment: Sure; there are situations where the post could be revealed without inadvertently leaking sensitive information, @Roko. Identifying these scenarios is not so easy though: the system would have to take into account a lot of extra information. I checked your reputation history... The user deletion that probably motivated this request would've been trivial for you to identify if you knew which answer the vote was associated with, simply because of the context surrounding that answer. Now imagine you'd also had one or two other votes reversed at the same time...

Comment: @Shog9 OK, I thought about cases where a single user upvoted (i.e:) 20+ answers (of another single user) and than got deleted > One'd than get 20+ links to associated answers, might seem stupid to have such a noisy feature costing the process overwhelming cycles/queries... I seem to get to the point of such (in more cases exaggerated) secrecy potentially exposing unwanted *fairness/policy* vulnerabilities.

Comment: Only tangentially related, but [you might enjoy this paper](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_oak08netflix.pdf) @Ruko.

Comment: Wait, the "User was Removed" line doesn't tell us who was removed, just that *a* user was removed. So it would still be anonymous, right?

Comment: Assuming they never wrote anything that could be used to identify them in any of their posts, sure @TylerH. Also everyone has to have really bad memories and archive.org needs to stop existing and...

Comment: @Shog9 Hmm, I am only thinking of the reputation page

Comment: Either your explanation is wrong, or there's a security hole in the mobile apps, because they [happily reveal this information](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311612/app-reveals-which-posts-lost-votes-when-user-was-removed-even-though-that-inf).

Comment: I wrote what I thought was a pretty good answer.  It got an upvote but then the user who upvoted it was removed and I lost the 10 points.  Ok, it happens.  But my answer was also deleted with no explanation.  And it isn't in my deleted answers view either. The question itself was closed after I had posted my answer but still remains.  So obviously it wasn't the OP who upvoted it.  Anyone know why this happened.

Answer (score 3):

The SEDE has a week old data dump, you can compare your answer scores to the score of your current one on your user page. If you don't have too many answers, you can find the result in some minutes.

On this way, you will know, where you've got an upvote from a crap account. But, honestly... why is it important, where you've got a false up from a crap account? I see no value in this information.

It is similar to that I see no value to know the subject of the mails filtered out by my spam filter.

Comment: what is "the SEDE" and where do we find this data dump?

Comment: @billynoah https://data.stackexchange.com . It is a partial dump of the MSSQL database of the Stack Exchange. It has all the questions, answers, comments, users and so on. All the not public data (for example, who voted to what) are not included into it. It does not use their productive database, instead it uses its mirror, synchronized weekly (always around monday 6:00 UTC). Thus, using SEDE queries, you can get the public data not available on the main sites any more, until the next monday morning.

Comment: @billynoah My pleasure :-) You can also create various, more complex graphs and stats, you can learn a lot from the SE with them.