# App reveals which posts lost votes when "user was removed", even though that information is deliberately concealed on the website

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, ios-app, api

[According to Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/310859/1709587), the purpose of merely showing "User was removed" in the reputation history and no breakdown of which posts lost votes as a result is to prevent information leakage that could identify voters.

However, the mobile apps explicitly show this information. Bohuslav Burghardt [claims that the iOS app reveals it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310858/user-was-removed-10-ok-but-on-which-answer/310859#comment275304_310858) in the comments on Shog's post, and yesterday I saw the same on the Android app.

[image: Screenshot showing the discrepancy]

Surely this inconsistency can't be right? Either leaking the information is fine, in which case the website might as well show this information too, or it's not, in which case the apps shouldn't.

Comment: this is only information leakage if you can see this information on someone else's account. If you can only see what you voted on how is that a problem?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: These aren't posts the OP voted on; the interface is showing information about what some removed user voted on. This was previously deemed a bad thing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was fixed in the latest deploy of the API.